# Prove that in an Eulerian graph on 6 vertices, a subset of 5 vertices cannot form a clique

Tags: graph-theory

How to prove that an Eulerian Graph on 6 vertices cannot contain $K_5$? I could not think of a counter example either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** (assuming that an "Eulerian graph" is a connected graph whose vertices all have even degree)**:**

Suppose that your graph consists of $H \simeq K_5$ and another vertex $v$. At least one vertex of $H$, say $w$, must be connected to $v$. What is the degree of $w$?

Answer (score 1):

An Eulerian graph is connected with every vertex of even degree, and the vertices in a $K_5$ each have degree $4$. In order to connect a sixth vertex to a $K_5$, you need at least one of the vertices on the $K_5$ to have an extra edge, raising its degree to $5$, which of course is odd.